# RC circuit not ideal sampling

Tags: circuit-analysis, fourier, sampling, nyquist-plot

I have this circuit and I have to find \$x(t)\$, starting from \$ x_c (t) \$

I know that, at \$t=0\$, the switch is closed, so the capacitor is charged and, at the moment \$ x(n)T_c \$ the switch is open and the capacitor discharge on the resistance (with an exponential trend and an RC constant).

So I wrote that \$ x_c (t) = x(nT_c)s(t - nT_c) \$ where \$ s(t) = e^{- \frac{t}{RC} } \$ if \$ 0 < t < T_c \$ and \$0\$ for the rest.

But now I’m blocked. My book finds \$S(f)\$ and after the equalized filter transfer function.

I obtained that \$ S(f) = \frac{RC}{1 + RCf} \$ but this result is completely different from my book  \$ f_c = \frac{1}{T_c} \$ and we assume Nyquist condition is verified.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change $ to \$....

Comment: not $$ ........  This is a simple exponential decay for \$x_c(t)\$

Comment: Thank you for all the edit, \$ f_c = \frac{1}{T_c} \$ can’t be incorrect because it’s in the problem text

Comment: I sincerely don’t understand how to find \$ x_c \$ so I have read the solution but my book first finds \$ S(f) \$ but obtains a completely different formula from mine. I applied the Fourier transform of exponential, so I don’t understand my error

Comment: I did not understand your question. Do you mean something like this ? http://tinyurl.com/yyb6nwu9

Comment: the switch closes and reopens instantly in the \$ nTc \$ sampling instants , and I think this is the same thing your circuit does.

Comment: Well as you can see it is mixture of signals and very high current when the switch closes if everything is ideal so it is not a practical question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111281/discussion-between-elena-martini-and-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Comment: Yes but I understand why my book wrote \$ x_c \$ like I reported but I don’t understand why my Fourier transform of \$ S(f) \$ is incorrect. I obtained the same \$ s(t) \$ so I don’t understand what’s my mistake. This is an example, on my book , of not ideal sampling

Comment: I don't understand the assumptions. what is x(t)?  What is the point of the question?  what is n? duty cycle?

Comment: Find a better resource ..maybe https://www.penwatch.net/cms/fft_sampling/

Comment: The assumption are that \$ f_c = \frac{1}{f_c} \$ , that the Nyquist condition is verified and I have to rebuilt \$ x(t) \$ From \$ x_c (t) \$

Comment: You mean there is some current on the right and the output is a sampled signal on the left?

Comment: Yes , I think this is right

Comment: I still have no idea on all the assumptions http://tinyurl.com/y6zkqxse  It's insufficient detail to answer

Comment: But the RC filter does not provide adequate bandstop to sampling noise. Thus not Nyquist verified.

Comment: Hello to the ESE girl.This part is mostly ran from males so it is good to see another woman posting stuff here.  Overthrow male dominance!

Comment: "*where s(t)=... if 0<t<Tc **and 0 for the rest**.*". So \$s(t) = \exp(-t/RC)\cdot( u(t) - u(t-T_s) )\$. For this specific signal, \$S(f) \neq \frac{RC}{1 + RC\cdot f}\$ because of the presence of *multiplication with a pulse signal*. Can you [edit] in more context to this question by adding more info from the text book ? If possible how the text book solves the question and the answer obtained by them.

Comment: Thank you :) I added all the photos of the solution on my book , where this exercise is solved ( should be , because I don’t see a value for \$ x(t) \$ ). Unfortunately is in Italian.. I understood the first and the second page, but on the third I obtained an \$ S(f) \$ that I wrote initially, and that’s completely different from my book

Comment: You can note that numerator of S(f) contains a term within parentheses \$(1 - \exp(-j\cdot 2 \pi \cdot f \cdot T_s))\$. I think that comes from the Laplace transfrom of \$u(t) - u(t-T_s)\$ as I have mentioned. Let me see if I can write it down as a proper answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111318/discussion-on-question-by-elena-martini-rc-circuit-not-ideal-sampling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP has mentioned,
\$s(t) = \exp(-t/RC)\$ for \$0 < t < T_c\$, **elsewhere zero**. i.e. it can be re written as

\$\color{red}{s(t) = \exp(-t/RC) \cdot (u(t) - u(t - T_c))}\$

\$s(t) = \exp(-t/RC) \cdot u(t) - \exp(-(t-T_c + T_c)/RC) \cdot u(t - T_c)\$

\$s(t)= \exp(-t/RC) \cdot u(t) - \exp(-T_c/RC) \exp(-(t-T_c)/RC) \cdot u(t - T_c) \$. taking Laplace transform (and using [time shifting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)),

\$S(w) = \frac{1}{w+1/RC} - \exp(-T_c/RC) \cdot \frac{\exp(-T_c \cdot w)}{w+1/RC}\$

\$S(w) = \frac{1}{w+1/RC} (1 - \exp(-T_c/RC) \cdot \exp(-T_c w))\$

The above equation is what seems to be present on top of page 22.

Note that I have used \$w\$ as the Laplace variable since \$s\$ is already being used for another purpose.

Comment: Since I cannot read Italian, OP needs to verify the steps themselves and check for agreement with the text book.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!now the result is the same my book obtained. I have to ask you one more thing , I usually  solve this circuit In the time domain , avoid the Laplace transform but I should obtain your same result. In the second formula you wrote \$ s(t) \$ , at this point ( also for avoid Laplace ) can I make the Fourier transform to obtain directly \$ S(f) \$ ?

Comment: Yes, Fourier transform also has a [time shifting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Translation_/_time_shifting). Laplace transform is usually defined with a built-in multiplication with \$u(t)\$. That is why I used Laplace transform.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!